# How loading of file into memory in perl

Tags: perl, sorting, memory, mmap

i have tried with some script for sorting a input text file in descending order and print only top usage customer.

input text file containts:

```
  NAME,USAGE,IP
  example :
  Abc,556,10.2.3.5
  bbc,126,14.2.5.6
```

and so on, this is very large file and i am trying to avoid loading file into memory.

I have tried with following script.

```
use warnings ;

use strict;

my %hash = ();
my $file = $ARGV[0] ;


open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open the file $file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh>) 
{
chomp ($line) ;
my( $name,$key,$ip) = split /,/, $line;

$hash{$key} = [ $name, $ip ];
}

my $count= 0 ;

foreach ( sort { $b <=> $a } keys %hash ){
my $value = $hash{$_};
print "$_  @{$value} \n" ;
last if (++$count == 5);
}
```

Output should be sorted based on usage and it will show the name and IP for respective usage. "    `

Comment: So you want to print the five lines of the file that have the highest value iun the second column?

Comment: yes, i want to print only 5 top lines from second column after sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to print the five lines of the file that have the highest value in the second column

That can be done by a sort of insertion sort that checks each line of the file to see if it comes higher than the lowest of the five lines most recently found, but it's easier to just accumulate a sensible subset of the data, sort it, and discard all but the top five

Here, I have array `@top` containing lines from the file. When there are 100 lines in the array, it is sorted and reduced to the five maximal entries. Then the `while` loop continues to add lines to the file until it reaches the limit again or the end of the file has been reached, when the process is repeated. That way, no more than 100 lines from the file are ever help in memory

I have generated a 1,000-line data file to test this with random values between 100 and 2,000 in column 2. The output below is the result

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh, '<', 'usage.txt' or die $!;

my @top;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    push @top, $_;

    if ( @top >= 100 or eof ) {

        @top = sort {
            my ($aa, $bb) = map { (split /,/)[1] } ($a, $b);
            $bb <=> $aa;
        } @top;

        @top = @top[0..4];
    }
}

print @top;
```

#### output

```
qcmmt,2000,10.2.3.5
ciumt,1999,10.2.3.5
eweae,1998,10.2.3.5
gvhwv,1998,10.2.3.5
wonmd,1993,10.2.3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is to create a priority queue that contains `k` items, where `k` is the number of items you want to return. So if you want the five lines that have the highest value, you'd do the following:

```
pq = new priority_queue
add the first five items in the file to the priority queue
for each remaining line in the file
    if value > lowest value on pq
        remove lowest value on the pq
        add new value to pq
```

When you're done going through the file, pq will contain the five items with the highest value.

To do this in Perl, use the [Heap::Priority](http://search.cpan.org/~fwojcik/Heap-Priority-0.11/Priority.pm) module.

This will be faster and use less memory than the other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm remembering the last 5 biggest rows.

For each row, check with the lowest memorized element. If more - are stored in the array before next biggest item with unshift lowest.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = $ARGV[0] ;
my @keys=(0,0,0,0,0);
my @res;

open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open the file $file: ";
while(<$fh>)
{
 my($name,$key,$ip) = split /,/;
 next if($key<$keys[0]);
 for(0..4) {
  if($_==4 || $key<$keys[$_+1]) {
   @keys[0..$_-1]=@keys[1..$_] if($_>0);
   $keys[$_]=$key;
   $res[$_]=[ $name, $ip ];
   last;
  } 
 }
}
for(0..4) {
  print "$keys[4-$_]  @{$res[4-$_]}";
}
```

Test on file from 1M random rows (20 Mbytes):

```
Last items (This algorithm):
Start 1472567980.91183
End   1472567981.94729 (duration 1.03546 seconds)

full sort in memory (Algorithm of @Rishi):
Start 1472568441.00438
End   1472568443.43829 (duration 2.43391 seconds)

sort by parts of 100 rows (Algorithm of @Borodin):
Start 1472568185.21896
End   1472568195.59322 (duration 10.37426 seconds)
```